# Bot-framework v4.0 : how to get the user's timezone

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, botframework

I'm trying to create a bot with skype channel, the bot can be used worldwide. The user can query the the bot the list of all skype calls between two dates X and Y. The problem is that all calls are saved in the database in GMT timezone and i need to get the user's time zone in order to show the right list of calls.

I haven't found any information for the user's timezone in the DialogContext object.

Comment: You may have to ask that info explicitly from the user.

Comment: I thought about it but according to the specifications the user cannot be truste, he may give us false information.

Comment: Yeah, and in that case its user's fault. I don't think Skype exposes any data related to current timezone info to the bot framework. Just to be sure, check the channel data of any of the messages (while debugging). More Info about channel data can be found [here](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/03/28/custom-channel-data/)

Comment: The bot framework should connect to other computers (and database) using GMT and convert any user input to GMT.  It shouldn't be necessary to get user timezone.  The DateTime object in c# is in GMT and users the computer timezone settings to/from convert GMT when converting from user input/output strings.

Comment: @jdweng, that last point is not true. C# `DateTime` is tri-state based on `.Kind`, and does not automatically convert. Your description applies to JavaScript's `Date` object, but not to C#.

Comment: @SoufienHajji - Please clarify:  Are you needing to convert values from your *own* database (in which case you would need the user's time zone), or are you working with `Activity` objects in the bot framework? (in which case you can use the [`Activity.LocalTimestamp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.activity.localtimestamp?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Schema_Activity_LocalTimestamp) property)

Comment: @MattJohnson In my database i have the calls that are made from all the users, these calls are saved in GMT timezone. The problem is that when the user says to the bot "I want to list all my calls from 10AM to 12AM" i need to convert the user's time inputs into GTM to make the right query to my database.
That's why i need the user's timezone.

Comment: @MattJohnson Are you sure that the Activity.LocalTimestamp property is existed in Skype for business channel ? from what i know it's not, but it's existed in web-chat channel.

Comment: Nope, not sure at all. I'm just browsing documentation. Haven't seen any code here. Would be good if you could share some in your question.